# How to adjust the positioning of the custom dialog box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a custom dialog box, now I need to position the custom dialog box to a desired position how can i do that in an .html.erb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the widget .dialog() **jQuery UI provides an option to change the position** of your dialog box.

Using it is as simple as : `$("#selector").dialog({position:"center"}); // center is default value`

or later with `$("#selector").dialog("option","position","center");`

Possible values :

- a single string representing position within viewport: 'center', 'left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'.
- an array containing an x,y coordinate pair in pixel offset from left, top corner of viewport (e.g. [350,100])
- an array containing x,y position string values (e.g. ['right','top'] for top right corner).